# Angular updating multiples of same parameter using $location.path.search

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way setting multiple query parameters of the same key using `$location.path.search`

i.e. `/categloue?cat=tents&cat=fourperson`

It only uses the last item..

```
$location.path('/categloue').search({ cat: 'tents', cat: 'fourperson' })
```

gives

i.e. `/categloue?cat=fourperson`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if your query string contains multiple items of the same key, it's considered an array.  So in your situation, this should work:

```
$location.path('/categloue').search({ cat: ['tents', 'fourperson'] })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way you are describing, but you'd need to set different keys! In your code, you are defining the same key twice.

You could try:

```
$location.path('/categloue').search({ cat: "tents", subcat: "fourperson" })
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks for your reply, unfortunately as there are 200+ filters and you can use a combination of filters at one time and on multiple levels it's been set up with multiples of the same keys which is interpreted server side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to create the query's as a string and pass them into just the $location.url

```
var area = '?cat=tents' + '&cat=fourperson';
$location.url('/en/tiles' + area)
```